# How many strings of six lowercase letters from the English alphabet contain the letters *a* and *b* with all letters different?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many strings of six lowercase letters from the English alphabet contain the letters *a* and *b* with all letters different? Answer: 7650720

I saw a resolution that considered the two types of strings different:

1) Possible strings not containing *a* nor *b*.

2) Possible strings not containing *a* and *b*.

But I do not understand why. Can someone explain or present another solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one solution: there are $6$ choices for the position of *a*, and then $5$ choices for the position of $b$. After this we have $24$ remaining possibilities for the next letter (because all letters must be distinct, and we have used two letters already), and then $23$ possibilities, and so on... We then apply the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to give

$$6 \cdot 5 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 = 7650720$$

To address your other question, consider the string ‘xya’. It is a string ‘not containing *a* and *b*’ because it doesn’t contain both *a* and *b*, but it is not a string ‘containing *a* nor *b*’ because it contains *a*.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

- First, calculate how many sets of 6 different letters that include *a* and *b* there are. The two letters are fixed so we have 24 remaining letters at our disposal and we need to pick 4. It is possible in $\binom{24}{4}$ ways.
- Second, calculate the number of permutations of each such set. Clearly, this is $6!$.
- Finally, multiply the two numbers to get the total:

$$\binom{24}{4} \cdot 6! = 7650720$$